# How to run Python- postgresql in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to test pyhton-postgresql script in ubuntu 12.04.

The script is this:

```
    import psycopg2
    import sys


    con = None

    try:

            con = psycopg2.connect(database='mydb', user='myuser') 
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("SQL")
    con.commit()


   except psycopg2.DatabaseError, e:

   if con:
         con.rollback()

   print 'Error %s' % e    
   sys.exit(1)


 finally:

     if con:
          con.close()
```

and the error I get each time I run the script from the terminal (`python myscript.py`) is:

```
Error  could not connect server: No such file or directory 
Is the server running locally and accepting connection on unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I don't have any idea what this mean, and I have been looking around for a while now. All to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the script, or atleast the lines you use to connect to the db?

Comment: @Salem Thanks I have posted an extract from the script

Comment: And PostgreSQL is installed and running? You can connect to it using `psql` or PgAdmin?

Comment: PostgreSQL is installed and it's running. Do I need to do any configuration before I can use psql or PgAdmin?

Comment: No. By default it should let you connect if they are on the same machine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9698/discussion-between-kplus-and-salem)

Comment: @Salem When I used both (pgsql and PgAdmin) I got import error : No Module named PgAdmin

Comment: http://www.pgadmin.org/screenshots/

Comment: @Salem How would my script look like if I am to use either of pgsql or PgAdmin.

Comment: @Salem  Thanks. I was able to connect to the database from the PgAdmin GUI where I was able to run quries. But I want it connect with python script. Thanks